# Find Anti-derivative in R

Tags: r, math, integral

I want to be able to find the anti-derivative of an arbitrary function in R.

Suppose I´ve got `f = 1/(2*x^2)` and want to find F, which by the way is easy to calculate by hand.

I´ve tried the following:

`f<- function (x) {1/(sqrt(x))}`

`F = antiD(f)`

This gives me:

`Error: no applicable method for 'rhs' applied to an object of class "function"`

Can someone give me a push in the right direction here?

Answer (score 5):

Are you using the mosaicCalc package?

I don't think you can use a function as argument to the antiD(). It expects a formula:

```
F <- antiD( 1/sqrt(x) ~ x)
```

This will give you a function F that takes two parameters x and C (constant). In this instance, it can't do a symbolic integration as it doesn't know what to do with the sqrt() function. If you alternatively did:

```
F <- antiD(x^-0.5 ~ x)
```

Then you'll see that symbolic integration has been done:

```
F
function (x, C = 0) {2 * x^(1/2) + C}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Ryacas`:

```
library(Ryacas)
yac_str("Integrate(x) 1/Sqrt(x)")
# [1] "2*Sqrt(x)"
```